# how to use Loops in Terraform to deploy 2 different azure resources

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm currently writing some Terraform code that deploys Azure Datalake Gen2 Storage Filesystem and folder structure for each filesystem.

Below code works fine when creating all the filesystems declared in the variable list.

**variable.tf**

```
variable "product_unified_filesystem" {
   default =  [
     "product1",
     "product2",
     "product3"
     ]
}

variable "product_unified_subdirs" {
  default = [
    "subdirectory1",
    "subdirectory2",
    "subdirectory3"
  ]
}
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "unified-filesystem" {
  count              = length(var.product_unified_filesystem)
  name               = var.product_unified_filesystem[count.index] 
  storage_account_id = module.storage.id
}

resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_path" "unified-subdirs-1" {
  count              = length(var.product_unified_subdirs)
  path               = var.product_unified_subdirs[count.index]  
  filesystem_name    = "product1"
  storage_account_id = module.storage.id
  resource           = "directory"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_path" "unified-subdirs-2" {
  count              = length(var.product_unified_subdirs)
  path               = var.product_unified_subdirs[count.index]  
  filesystem_name    = "product2"
  storage_account_id = module.storage.id
  resource           = "directory"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_path" "unified-subdirs-3" {
  count              = length(var.product_unified_subdirs)
  path               = var.product_unified_subdirs[count.index]  
  filesystem_name    = "product3"
  storage_account_id = module.storage.id
  resource           = "directory"
  }
}
```

Now I want to create a common sub folder structure each of the product file system created above.

Above Code works when I pass one filesystem at a time to create the folder structure.

I want to loop through both variables and create a folder structure as shown below.

- product1
  subdirectory1
  subdirectory2
  subdirectory3
- product2
  subdirectory1
  subdirectory2
  subdirectory3
- product3
  subdirectory1
  subdirectory2
  subdirectory3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [setproduct](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/setproduct) to get all combinations. Also its better to use `for_each` instead of `count` as it does not depend on ordering of items.

```
locals {
  fs_subdir = {
    for val in setproduct(var.product_unified_filesystem, var.product_unified_subdirs):
      "${val[0]}-${val[1]}" => {
        product = val[0]
        subdir = val[1]
      }
  }
}
```

then

```
resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "unified-filesystem" {
  for_each           = toset(var.product_unified_filesystem)
  name               = each.key
  storage_account_id = module.storage.id
}

resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_path" "unified-subdirs" {
  for_each           = local.fs_subdir
  path               = each.value.subdir
  filesystem_name    = each.value.product
  storage_account_id = module.storage.id
  resource           = "directory"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marcin, Thank you very much
can i use setproduct to concat 3 variables 
variable "product_unified_filesystem" {
   default =  [
     "product1",
     "product2",
     "product3"
     ]
}
variable "product_unified_subdirs" {
  default = [
    "subdirectory1",
    "subdirectory2",
    "subdirectory3"
  ]
}
variable "product_unified_subdirs_folder" {
  default = [
    "folder1",
    "folder2",
    "folder3"
  ]
}
product1
 subdirectory1
  folder1
  folder2
  folder3
 subdirectory2
  folder1
  folder2
  folder3
 subdirectory3
  folder1
  folder2
  folder3

Comment: @Automation-Developer no problem. I think 3 variables should work. Try and if have issues, please make new question.